# Visual Basic - Create a variable that changes only the first time the program runs

Tags: vb.net

I'm creating an app in VB.net and I wanted to implement something for safety, a variable that changes only after the first time the program runs, after that is stays the same as read only.

There's a way to create something like this?

Comment: What do you mean by "for safety"?

Answer (score 1):

Variables are items in memory, and every time a program runs it gets all new memory. If you want a variable to persist across runs, you need to use storage that also persists, and load the variable from that storage each time the program runs: somewhere like a file or registry key.

The thing is, if the user running your program has the file system or registry permission needed to create the initial entry for your variable, they also have the permission to change or remove it between runs, and **there's nothing you can do about it.**

The best option you have is to hide it, but even then it's not hard for anyone to use [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) on your program to see exactly what it's looking at when it starts.

If you can be more specific about what, exactly, you're trying to accomplish, we might be able to suggest a better way to achieve that goal.

Comment: I see, sorry I'm a little new to programming.
I want my app to check a variable, if it's false them it creates information so the person using can log in.
If this variable is already true when the app start, it means it's not the copy for the person using it.

Probably it won't be that safe, I didn't knew about the Process Explorer.

Comment: "I want my app to check a variable."  No! That's _how_ you want to do it. Go into more detail about what you want to accomplish.

Comment: @Gonçalvez - What is "creates information"? You're being quite vague about what you want to do, but it sounds security related and what you're proposing doesn't seem very secure. That's why we're asking for more information. We want to help.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn good info, but you know this is not an answer.